# A Chebychev-like inequality using truncated second moment

Tags: probability, inequality, concentration-of-measure

I came across a claim in a paper that I think reduces to:

Given a real valued, zero mean random variable $X$ with finite second moment and a constant $t$:

$$\mathbb P ( |X| > \epsilon ) \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon^2}\mathbb E \left [ X^2 \mathbb 1 \{ X^2 > \epsilon^2\} \right ]$$

Which looks like Chebychev's inequality, except using a truncated second moment, rather than the variance. My proof:

$$\mathbb P ( X^2 > \epsilon ) = \mathbb P ( X^2 \mathbb 1 \{|X| > \epsilon\} > \epsilon ) \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon}\mathbb E\{X^2\mathbb 1 \{|X| > \epsilon\}\}$$

My question:

Is this result correct? Does it have a name?

Comment: What makes you think that it holds? The first result is straightforward, it's just Markov's inequality applied to the square of the truncated absolute. Chebyshev's inequality also applies, but $X1\{|X|>\epsilon\}$ is not centerd anymore.

Comment: Thanks @Matija, I made a correction (not longer claiming it is tighter than Chebychev)

Comment: Now, the last line is the same as the first. And I think there's a typo in the second line, at least this doesn't hold for $\epsilon>1$, and for $\epsilon<1$ the bound in the first line is better (since $\{|X|<\epsilon\}=\{X^2>\epsilon^2\}$).